# Is there a C# implementation of JWZ's message threading algorithm?

Tags: c#, email, open-source

Is there any open source implementation of [JWZ's threading algorithm](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) in C#?

Answer (score 9):

I've implemented Jamie Zawinski's threading algorithm (as well as the "Ordered Subject" threading algorithm described in [rfc5256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256)) in C# in [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).